# Why the WinDbg always return the same information of "!heap -s" when I test a memory leak program?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, windbg

I write a program to learn the memory leak detecting with WinDbg. But when I use the "!heap -s" command, it always return the same information(see below) after I run the memory leaking program for a long while.

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

*** wait with pending attach
Symbol search path is: srv*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;C:\image
Executable search path is: srv*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;C:\image
ModLoad: 00000000`00400000 00000000`0041a000   C:\image\memory.exe
ModLoad: 00000000`76d40000 00000000`76ee9000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`76f20000 00000000`770a0000   ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`001c0000 00000000`0022e000   C:\Windows\system32\verifier.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`731c0000 00000000`731ff000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`73160000 00000000`731bc000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64win.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`74850000 00000000`74858000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64cpu.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`6f7f0000 00000000`6f850000   VERIFIER.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`72a20000 00000000`72a49000   vrfcore.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`6f870000 00000000`6f8ac000   VFBASICS.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`76380000 00000000`76490000   KERNEL32.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`76490000 00000000`764d7000   KERNELBASE.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`10200000 00000000`10320000   MSVCR80D.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`74e20000 00000000`74ecc000   msvcrt.dll
(44e0.4748): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
00000000`76d90590 cc              int     3
0:001> !heap -s
LFH Key                   : 0x0000008a68294636
Termination on corruption : ENABLED
          Heap     Flags   Reserv  Commit  Virt   Free  List   UCR  Virt  Lock  Fast 
                            (k)     (k)    (k)     (k) length      blocks cont. heap 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000000000320000 00000002     512      8    512      3     1     1    0      0      
0000000003d80000 00001002     512      8    512      3     1     1    0      0      
0000000000310000 00008000      64      4     64      1     1     1    0      0      
00000000003a0000 00008000      64     64     64     61     1     1    0      0      
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0:001> g
(44e0.1550): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
00000000`76d90590 cc              int     3
0:001> g
(44e0.3b04): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
00000000`76d90590 cc              int     3
0:001> !heap -s
LFH Key                   : 0x0000008a68294636
Termination on corruption : ENABLED
          Heap     Flags   Reserv  Commit  Virt   Free  List   UCR  Virt  Lock  Fast 
                            (k)     (k)    (k)     (k) length      blocks cont. heap 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000000000320000 00000002     512      8    512      3     1     1    0      0      
0000000003d80000 00001002     512      8    512      3     1     1    0      0      
0000000000310000 00008000      64      4     64      1     1     1    0      0      
00000000003a0000 00008000      64     64     64     61     1     1    0      0      
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The program code are like below:

```
#include <windows.h>

void AllocateMemory() 
{ 

    int* a = new int[2000]; 
    ZeroMemory(a, 8000); 
    Sleep(1); 
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
while(1) 
{ 
    AllocateMemory(); 
} 
return 0; 
}
```

The gflag command like below:

```
C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x64)>gflags.exe -i memory.exe +ust
```

Comment: I tried this on both windows server 2008 and windows 7, the code was compiled with vs2005, and I use the debug version of the test program.

Comment: Are you running a release or debug build of your leak program? If release, then the optimizing compiler may have optimized away the call to new and ZeroMemory since the local variable a isn't used anywhere.

Comment: 6.12.0002.633 is rather old. You might also want to check if that's a bug in WinDbg by using Version 6.2.9200 or 6.3.9600. See my list of [WinDbg Versions](http://debugging.wellisolutions.de/windbg-versions/)

Comment: @ThomasW. Tried the Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.3.9600.17298 AMD64, still got the same result. :( And the 32bit version windbg didn't work either! :( :(

Answer (score 0):

i just modified the code a bit to aid me count iterations and ran it in 6.12 and used !heap -l to detect leaks windbg seems to report correctly see the count of BusyBlocks

```
#include <windows.h>
int count =0;
void AllocateMemory() {
    int* a = new int[2000]; 
    ZeroMemory(a, 8000); 
    Sleep(1);
    count++;
}
int main(void) {   
while(1) { 
    AllocateMemory(); 
} 
return 0; 
}
```

output from windbg

```
0:000> .printf "%y\n" ,@eip
leakmem!main (00401050)
0:000> ?? count ; !heap -l
int 0n0
Scanning references from 97 busy blocks (0 MBytes) ...No potential unreachable blocks were detected.
0:000> bp @eip+3 0n5
0:000> g
Breakpoint 0 hit
0:000> ?? count ; !heap -l
int 0n4
Scanning references from 101 busy blocks (0 MBytes) ...No potential unreachable blocks were detected.
0:000> bp 401053 0n15
breakpoint 0 redefined
0:000> bl
 0 e 00401053     000f (000f)  0:**** leakmem!main+0x3
0:000> g
Breakpoint 0 hit
0:000> ?? count ; !heap -l
int 0n19
Scanning references from 117 busy blocks (0 MBytes) ...
Entry     User      Heap      Segment       Size  PrevSize  Unused    Flags
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
00421f98  00421fa0  00030000  00410000      1f58      1f58        18  busy extra
 fill
00425e48  00425e50  00030000  00410000      1f58      1f58        18  busy extra
 fill
00435908  00435910  00030000  00420000      1f58      1f58        18  busy extra
 fill
00437860  00437868  00030000  00420000      1f58      1f58        18  busy extra
 fill
004397b8  004397c0  00030000  00420000      1f58      1f58        18  busy extra
 fill
5 potential unreachable blocks were detected.
0:000>
```

Comment: why when I use the command ".printf "%y\n" ,@eip", always got the "ntdll!DbgBreakPoint (77a0000c)". The output of `!heap -l` always detected no leak. `0:001> .printf "%y\n" ,@eip
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint (77a0000c)
0:001> g
(1bf4.1410): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
....//some informations ommited.
0:001> ?? count ; !heap -l
int 28567
Searching the memory for potential unreachable busy blocks.
Heap 03c50000
Heap 05150000
Heap 00240000
Heap 05410000
Scanning VM ...
Scanning references from 12 busy blocks (0 MBytes) ...No potential unreachable blocks were detected.`

Comment: the print is to show that i am at the start of  main() function it means i have used g Go after setting a breakpoint in main()  and the app has  broken in my breakpoint and i have cleared all the breakpoints prior to running the commands shows .printf is magic pill it is just a printf and will print out the symbol where your eip is at when you executing  you seem to have a some first chance excpetions enabled :( have you modified any event filters ? int3 first chance shouldnt show up iirc try running .sxcmds and try resetting all the sx * filters 12 busy blocks wont show any unreachable code

Comment: Did you use "Open Executable..." menu ? However, I use this menu, still don't work. It seems can't make a breakpoint int main. BTW, does the '!heap -l' command need the suspected program running some times, or just use it to determine which block has memory leaked ?

Comment: yes open executable -> select your exe -> g -> ctrl+break ->heap -l ->g -> ctrl+break -> !heap -l  that is 2 iteration

Comment: I haven't resolved my problem. Anyway, thank you for your kindly help.